# SELECT all value from table only once if they're duplicated

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table with the following rows/values:

```
+--------+----------+
|   ID   |  adspot  |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |        A |
|      2 |        B |
|      3 |        A |
|      4 |        B |
|      5 |        C |
|      6 |        A |
+--------+----------+
```

I need a way to select the values in adspot but *only once* if they're duplicated. So from this example I'd want to select A once and B once. The SQL result should look like this then:

```
+----------+
|  adspot  |
+----------+
|        A |
|        B |
|        C |
+----------+
```

I'm using mySQL and PHP, in case anyone asks.

Thanks.

Comment: Both Dre's and amosrivera's solutions worked great. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT adspot FROM your_table;` ( this may not perform well at all in large tables )

Comment: If you have an index on the column, performance will be fine even in large tables (no sorting/bucketing necessary).

Comment: Define large table. I've accumulated about 5,000 records in one month. I expect the growth rate to accelerate to over 10,000 new records each month.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT adspot FROM table GROUP BY adspot
```

see: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php

Comment: It works, but it is usually better (clearer, easier to understand) to use DISTINCT for this operation.